# Geting the value of a Field

Tags: java, android, class

I have an app in which all classes contain a `String track`. And all these classes call a `class Track`. How can I get the value of `track` from `class Track`? I expect something like

```
public Class Track{
getClass().trackorwhatever().get(this)
}
```

Comment: it is unclear what you want to do. The above code won't compile even if you used the correct construct. It is likely that you want the wrong thing

Comment: Just as with a natural language you can't just mix up words to get a sentence, you can't mix key words and get a program in Java.

Comment: @Snicolas I disagree. You can mix them but you should do it in the right way. Then you'll get a sentence/program or whatever. Isn't that what stackoverflow is about? Helping people to mix the keywords in the right way?

Comment: @bozho Surely it won't compile. I just typed it in for the sake of expressing the type of answer I'm expecting. Neeta understood. Sorry I couldn't make the question more direct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Track` class, make a method which returns the value of `track`:

```
public String getTrack()
{
 return track;
}
```

Have you declared an instance of class `Track` in your other classes?
If you have you can do something like this:

```
Track tr = new Track()
String track;
track = tr.getTrack();
```